# Why does WSO2 API Manager tryit feature fail?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have a configuration as follows:
1 server with seperate Publisher (9446) and Store (port 9447).  Both are configured with shared gov/config registry (note that the publisher is the same except localhost:9446/registry for the remote instance url:

```
<dbConfig name="govregistry">
    <dataSource>jdbc/WSO2SHAREDCONREG_DB</dataSource>
</dbConfig>
<remoteInstance url="https://localhost:9447/registry">
    <id>gov</id>
    <dbConfig>govregistry</dbConfig>
    <readOnly>false</readOnly>
    <enableCache>true</enableCache>
    <registryRoot>/</registryRoot>
</remoteInstance>
<mount path="/_system/governance" overwrite="true">
    <instanceId>gov</instanceId>
    <targetPath>/_system/governance</targetPath>
</mount>
<mount path="/_system/config" overwrite="true">
    <instanceId>gov</instanceId>
    <targetPath>/_system/nodes</targetPath>
</mount>
```

I have a Gateway and Key Manager on a different server.  These are both deployed to different directories and the WSO2 documentation did not say to do anything additional for the registry.xml file so they look like:

```
<currentDBConfig>wso2registry</currentDBConfig>
<dbConfig name="wso2registry">
    <dataSource>jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB</dataSource>
</dbConfig>
```

When the API is published and then I attempt to use the 'try it' functionality I get the following error (regardless of if the API is set to require a token or not)...
This error is on the gateway server:

```
[2014-01-23 21:54:31,111] ERROR - APIAuthenticationHandler API authentication failure
org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APISecurityException: Access failure for API: /newphoneverify, version: 1.0.0 with key: null
```

Do I need to do something additional like setting up governance and config registry sharing on the keymanager and gateway as well?

Answer (score 0):

This happens if the OPTIONS verb of the API is not enabled with 'None' auth type. Check [1].

[1]https://wso2.org/jira/browse/APIMANAGER-1819

Comment: Sadly, my API is already set correctly for the OPTIONS type. It is currently and has always been set to 'None' with throttleing of 'Unlimited'.  So that JIRA, while the error logs match my problem, it doesn't appear to be the same.  Is logging JIRA issues the right action?  Or posting issues to Stackoverflow?

Comment: Jira is used if it is a bug. Stackoverflow can be used to get assistence from the community. Can I know your APIM version? Please send a curl request to your API to check the respose for the OPTIONS method. ex: 'curl -v -X http://localhost:8280/api. What is the response message you get?

Comment: I get an html page...I'll add an answer.

Comment: Thanks. IN 1.6.0 we did some CORS improvements. So you need to configure your API Store addresses in api-manager.xml. Here need to configure both http and https address of the store in Access-Control-Allow-Origin parameter. http://docs.wso2.org/display/AM160/Adding+Documentation+Using+Swagger. Then restart the server. After that first thing we need to do is get the OPTIONS call working with success response. Let me know the OPTIONS call response after this change.

Comment: Will try with the twitter sample included with that doc...will post as an answer.

Comment: Please note that I tried making the updates as you suggested, both to a distributed install and a stand alone.  Neither worked.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem:

Swagger UI does not works and return the same screenshots above, but if I use chrome/postman the API return the correct value so is just the swagger UI that has problems, I have an Apache in front of the API manager and the external name of the store is different from the internal name and apache proxypass the request.

I have configured the api-manager.xml and the API does not have authorization (all set to none) have really no idea on how to fix it.

Comment: Yeah, me neither...I have stopped looking at this point, will take someone whom is smarted than I.